# quartz 2.1.5 + jboss 5.0.1 -> job class -> classNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, quartz-scheduler, classnotfoundexception, jboss5.x

I have a job with name `Myjob.java` under package `com.example.jobs`.  This class is in a war: `example.war`.

I have used following config in jboss in file `quartz-service.xml` present in deploy folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<server> 
<mbean code="org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService" name="user:service=QuartzService,name=QuartzService"> 
<depends>jboss.web.deployment:war=/example</depends> 
<attribute name="JndiName">Quartz</attribute> 
<attribute name="Properties"> 
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler 
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 4 
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = ${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/quartz-jobs.xml 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 120 
</attribute> 
</mbean> 
</server>
```

and under conf i have `quartz-jobs.xml` file having following:

```
<job-scheduling-data version="1.8" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"> 

<pre-processing-commands><delete-jobs-in-group>*</delete-jobs-in-group> 
<delete-triggers-in-group>*</delete-triggers-in-group> 
</pre-processing-commands><processing-directives> 
<overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data> 
<ignore-duplicates>false</ignore-duplicates> 
</processing-directives> 

<schedule> 
<job> 
<name>TestJob</name> 
<job-class>com.example.jobs.Myjob</job-class> 
</job> 

<trigger> 
<cron> 
<name>TestCronTrigger</name> 
<job-name>TestJob</job-name> 
<cron-expression>* * * * * ?</cron-expression> 
</cron> 
</trigger> 
</schedule> 

</job-scheduling-data>
```

On running jboss I get following:

```
2012-05-29 16:10:38,527 INFO [main] [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.5) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED' 
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally. 
NOT STARTED. 
Currently in standby mode. 
Number of jobs executed: 0 
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 5 threads. 
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

followed by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.jobs.Myjob from BaseClassLoader@7aeb46d{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@5ec7640b{name=vfsfile:/D:/Datatocopy/openlogic-jboss-5.0.1.GA-all-bin-1/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/slim/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@c4ce427{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@7e5a9de6} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@            1954102985      [path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o2zz-ms2vbd-h2su3au9-1-h2su3igd-t real=vfsmemory://5c4o2zz-ms2vbd-h2su3au9-1-h2su3igd-t]] delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}} 
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:422) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) 
at org.quartz.simpl.InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.loadClass(InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.java:72) 
at org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:114) 
at org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:138) 
at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.process(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:653) 
at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.processFile(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:503) 
at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.processFileAndScheduleJobs(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:886) 
at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.processFile(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:330) 
at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.start(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:257) 
at org.quartz.plugins.SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.start(SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.java:144) 
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.startPlugins(QuartzScheduler.java:2343) 
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:527) 
at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:143) 
at org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService.startService(QuartzService.java:270) 
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376) 
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:322) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) 
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) 
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) 
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264) 
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668) 
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:189) 
at $Proxy36.start(Unknown Source) 
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42) 
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) 
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553) 
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688) 
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460) 
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163) 
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99) 
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46) 
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) 
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50) 
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171) 
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439) 
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157) 
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178) 
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822) 
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553) 
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781) 
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698) 
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304) 
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205) 
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405) 
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209) 
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: added code quido please guide now as to what could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be a classloader problem; in file

```
${jboss.server}/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/META-INF/jboss-service.xml
```

find the line

```
<attribute name="UseJBossWebLoader">false</attribute>
```

and set it to `true`.

Note: `${jboss.server} = ${your jboss path}/server/${your server name}`

EDIT for jboss5:

find the file (the same of your comment):

```
deployers/jbossweb.deploy/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml
```

and comment out the `WarClassLoaderDeployer`

Explanation and an alternative way to fix [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/useJBossWebClassLoaderinJBoss5).

Comment: hi i am using jboss 5.0.1 there is no jboss-service.xml file...at said path however the said property in file:server\slim\deployers\jbossweb.deployer\META-INF\war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml and said property is already true.

Comment: Hi thanx guido it worked like charm.. however i would loke to know about the classloading concept how actually it works.. any external links you could provide.Also I hope this is the only way to work it out. will there be any impacts?

Comment: welcome. Look at the link I provided in the foot of my answer; basically in that way you circumvent the default which is having an isolated classloader for each war deployed. IN the same link you can find an alternative solution; or you could split your jobs in an ear, and make quartz mbean depend on that instead of the war.

Comment: just a general question: should there be multiple jobs with different triggers in single schedule, or one job per schedule what must be preferred when and why

Comment: that i dont know, i'd prefer for one job per schedule, however it depends on your needs; what i know is that you should definitely improve you answer acceptance ratio.

Comment: ok, thanks the question is answered and answer has been accepted

Comment: You should click the green "check" image on left side of accepted answer for actually accepting an answer. You should do that also for your old questions, that's for helping other people which come here with same problem, the check mark tells them that a solution actually works.